# connect to websites using Tor C++ (sockets)

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to connect to the web through Tor in my C++ application.To begin,I thought that getting the html code of a website would be greatI downloaded the tor expert bundle,and it runs fine (firefox is able to use it as a socks5 proxy)
Now here's the code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#define MSG_NOSIGNAL 0


#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
int main()
{

    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
}
    std::cout << " [*] Tor" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " [*] Connecting " << std::endl;

    SOCKET      Socket;
    SOCKADDR_IN SocketAddr;

    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    SocketAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SocketAddr.sin_port = htons(9050);
    SocketAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)&SocketAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

    char Req1[3] =
    {
        0x05, // SOCKS 5
        0x01, // One Authentication Method
        0x00  // No AUthentication
    };
    send(Socket, Req1, 3, MSG_NOSIGNAL);

    char Resp1[2];
    recv(Socket, Resp1, 2, 0);
    if (Resp1[1] != 0x00)
    {
        std::cout << " [*] Error Authenticating " << std::endl;
        return(-1); // Error
    }

    std::cout << " [*] Fetching... " << std::endl;
    char* Domain = "www.google.com";
    char  DomainLen = (char)strlen(Domain);
    short Port = htons(80);

    char TmpReq[4] = {
        0x05, // SOCKS5
        0x01, // CONNECT
        0x00, // RESERVED
        0x03, // DOMAIN
    };

    char* Req2 = new char[4 + 1 + DomainLen + 2];

    memcpy(Req2, TmpReq, 4);                // 5, 1, 0, 3
    memcpy(Req2 + 4, &DomainLen, 1);        // Domain Length
    memcpy(Req2 + 5, Domain, DomainLen);    // Domain
    memcpy(Req2 + 5 + DomainLen, &Port, 2); // Port

    send(Socket, (char*)Req2, 4 + 1 + DomainLen + 2, MSG_NOSIGNAL);

    delete[] Req2;

    char Resp2[10];
    recv(Socket, Resp2, 10, 0);
    if (Resp2[1] != 0x00)
    {
        std::cout << " [*] Error : " << Resp2[1] << std::endl;
        return(-1); // ERROR
    }

    std::cout << " [*] Connected " << std::endl;


    // Test with a HTTP GET Request
    std::cout << " [*] Testing with GET Request \n" << std::endl;
    char * request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\n\r\n\r\n";
    send(Socket, request, strlen(request), MSG_NOSIGNAL);
    char RecvBuffer[2048];
    int ndatalength;
    ndatalength = 1;

    while (ndatalength != 0) {
        if (ndatalength == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "error on connection" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        ndatalength = recv(Socket, RecvBuffer, 2048, 0);

    }

    std::cout << RecvBuffer;

    return(0);
```

}

The problem is,instead of printing the html code of the page,it returns this kind of thing :[image: program] and then stops working.If I choose "undefined" in caracter set options instead of Unicode,I get this :
[image]
(this is a part of the total output),and the exe stops working after that.
What's wrong here ?
I'm using Visual Studio 2017 64bits on windows 10 Pro Fall creators Update.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:adding WSAstartup solves (almost) the problem :
[image: strange]
What are these caracters ? They are after the end of the html code...

Comment: I believe that `recv` does not nul terminate the string.You need to do that.

Comment: Using `memset(RecvBuffer, 0x00, 2047);`makes the app display less text,but still not html code,and it keeps stopping working

Comment: 'recv(Socket, Resp2, 10, 0);' always a fail.  recv() returns a value that you MUST correctly and completely handle, (consider this with @JohnnyMopp comment above).

Comment: What do you mean by "correctly and completely" ?

Comment: @EinderJam `recv` returns -1 on error, 0 on graceful disconnect by the peer, and > 0 for the number of bytes actually read. You need to handle all three conditions. And in the last case, if the number of bytes read is less than the number of bytes you are expecting, call `recv` again to read the remaining bytes

Comment: Partially solved my problem,see the EDIT